# Create Column with ELIF in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

**Question**

I am having trouble figuring out how to create new DataFrame column based on the values in two other columns.  I need to use if/elif/else logic.  But all of the documentation and examples I have found only show if/else logic.  Here is a sample of what I am trying to do:

**Code**

```
df['combo'] = 'mobile' if (df['mobile'] == 'mobile') elif (df['tablet'] =='tablet') 'tablet' else 'other')
```

I am open to using where() also.  Just having trouble finding the right syntax.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In cases where you have multiple branching statements it's best to create a function that accepts a row and then apply it along the `axis=1`. This is usually much faster then iteration through rows.

```
def func(row):
    if row['mobile'] == 'mobile':
        return 'mobile'
    elif row['tablet'] =='tablet':
        return 'tablet' 
    else:
        return 'other'

df['combo'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

Comment: `This is usually much faster then iteration through rows.` -- doesn't this approach iterate through rows as well?

Answer (score 48):

I tried the following and the result was much faster. Hope it's helpful for others.

```
df['combo'] = 'other'
df.loc[df['mobile'] == 'mobile', 'combo'] = 'mobile'
df.loc[df['tablet'] == 'tablet', 'combo'] = 'tablet'
```

Comment: This is the method recommended in the pandas cookbook.  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/cookbook.html#idioms

Comment: `.ix()` is officially deprecated. I am updating this answer with the current cookbook solution.

Comment: FYI for others. In my own specific example of using `df.apply()` `242ms +- 1.98ms` vs. `.loc`  `213ms +- 1.3ms` on about `3900` rows. Done using `%%timeit`.

Answer (score 28):

`ELIF` logic can be implemented with [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) or nested [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np

df['combo'] = np.select([df.mobile == 'mobile', df.tablet == 'tablet'], 
                        ['mobile', 'tablet'], 
                        default='other')
# or 
df['combo'] = np.where(df.mobile == 'mobile', 'mobile', 
                       np.where(df.tablet == 'tablet', 'tablet', 'other'))
```

#### Sample Data + Output:

```
   mobile  tablet   combo
0  mobile     bar  mobile
1     foo  tablet  tablet
2     foo     nan   other
3  mobile  tablet  mobile
4  mobile     nan  mobile
5     foo  tablet  tablet
6  mobile     bar  mobile
7  mobile  tablet  mobile
8  mobile     bar  mobile
9  mobile     nan  mobile
```

Comment: this really should be the accepted solution; it's scalable, and it doesn't even require an additional import: `pd.np.select`.

Comment: ageed - I can't get any of these calling functions to work.

Comment: how would you do an 'in' statement: example 
`df['combo'] = np.where(df.device in ('moblile, 'Mobile', 'Phone'), 'mobile'
, np.where(df.device like '%tablet%', 'tablet', 'other'))`

Comment: @GenDemo you can use `isin` for checking if something is in a list: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960077/how-to-filter-pandas-dataframe-using-in-and-not-in-like-in-sql. IIU the other logic, for the like you can use `Series.str.contains('tablet', case=False)`

Comment: @ALollz thank you.

I came right with 
`sale_method = pd.DataFrame(model_data['Sale Method'].str.upper())
sale_method['sale_classification'] = np.where(sale_method['Sale Method'].isin (['PRIVATE']), 'private'
                                        ,np.where(sale_method['Sale Method'].str.contains('AUCTION'), 'auction'
                                        , 'other'))`

Answer (score 3):

Adding to np.where solution :

```
df['col1']= np.where(df['col'] < 3, 1,np.where( (df['col'] >3 )& (df['col'] <5),2,3))
```

Overall Logic is :

```
np.where(Condition, 'true block','false block').
```

With each true/false block can in turn  again be nested.

Also, Notice the `&` for `ANDing! (not 'and')`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to apply lambda solution :

```
 df['combo'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'mobile' if x['mobile'] == 'mobile' else \
                                 ('tablet' if x[''mobile']== 'tablet' else 'other'), axis=1)
```

Structure :

```
df['column_name'] = df.apply(lambda x: 'value if true 1' if x['column_name_check_1'] == 'condition_1' else 
                                      ('value if true 2' if x['column_name_check_2'] == 'condition_2' else 
                                      ('value if true 3' if x['column_name_check_3'] == 'condition_3' else 'default_value')),axis=1)
```

Note :
axis 1 for format value as column / series