# Create dataframe column with elif of different types in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

This is an extension of [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194404/create-column-with-elif-in-pandas).

I'd like to do some if/elif/else logic to create a dataframe column, pseudocode example:

```
if Col1 = 'A' and Col2 = 1 then Col3 = 'A1'
else if Col1 = 'A' and Col2 = 0 then Col3 = 'A0'
else Col3 = 'XX'
```

is it ok to mix up the types there? I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [int64] array with a scalar of type [bool]

Comment: You use single `=` sign to compare instead of `==` I think that my cause an issue

Comment: yes, sorry, was just using pseudocode. should have done if df.['Col1'] == 'A'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
df['Col3'] = 'XX'
df.loc[(df.Col1 == 'A') & (df.Col2 == 1), 'Col3'] = 'A1'
df.loc[(df.Col1 == 'A') & (df.Col2 == 0), 'Col3'] = 'A0'
```

With double [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df["Col3"] = np.where((df.Col1 == 'A') & (df.Col2 == 1) , "A1", 
             np.where((df.Col1 == 'A') & (df.Col2 == 0), 'A0', 'XX'))
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['A','B','A','B'],
                   'Col2':[1,1,0,0]})

print (df)
  Col1  Col2
0    A     1
1    B     1
2    A     0
3    B     0

df['Col3'] = 'XX'
df.loc[(df.Col1 == 'A') & (df.Col2 == 1), 'Col3'] = 'A1'
df.loc[(df.Col1 == 'A') & (df.Col2 == 0), 'Col3'] = 'A0'

df["Col4"] = np.where((df.Col1 == 'A') & (df.Col2 == 1) , "A1", 
             np.where((df.Col1 == 'A') & (df.Col2 == 0), 'A0', 'XX'))

print (df)
  Col1  Col2 Col3 Col4
0    A     1   A1   A1
1    B     1   XX   XX
2    A     0   A0   A0
3    B     0   XX   XX
```