# New column based on conditional

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Currently trying to change some market values in a dataframe if some value is present in another column. I'm only familiar with list comprehension for creating new columns, but im not sure its possible to do it this way.

I tried the following function, though it doesn't work:

```py
def multiply_with(x):
    if df['a'] in list_multiple_double: 
        x = x * 0.5
    elif df['a'] in list_multiple_triple:  
        x = x * 0.33
    else: 
        x = x
    return x
```

I tried applying this on the market value column, but no luck.

Assume there are two columns a and b in a pd.dataframe, and i would like to create c. Also assume 2 lists, `list_a` and `list_b`. For every observation, if `a` is present in `list_a` then multiply by 0.5 and return this in column `c`. If `a` is present in `list_`b then multiply by 0.333 and return in `c`. If not present either return `a` in `c`. I need the following:

```py
list_a = ['Denmark Sweden', 'Norway Sweden']
list_b = ['Denmark Sweden Norway']


values = [200,300,500,1000,200]
country = ['Denmark', 'Denmark Sweden', 'Denmark Sweden Norway', 'Sweden', 'Norway']
values_adj = [200, 150, 166.67, 1000, 200]

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['values'] = pd.Series(values)
df['country'] = pd.Series(country)
df['values_adj'] = pd.Series(values_adj)
```

Comment: please add a sample data and final expected output with your explanation. thanks

Comment: What happens when it's just Denmark? Would it return just the same value without multiplication?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Column with ELIF in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194404/create-column-with-elif-in-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [np.select](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
df['values_adj'] = np.select([df['country'].isin(list_a), df['country'].isin(list_b)], [df['values']*0.5, df['values']*0.333], df['values'])

print(df)
```

Output:

```
values                country  values_adj
0     200                Denmark       200.0
1     300         Denmark Sweden       150.0
2     500  Denmark Sweden Norway       166.5
3    1000                 Sweden      1000.0
4     200                 Norway       200.0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df['values_adj'] = df['values']
df.loc[df['country'].isin(list_a), 'values_adj'] *= 0.5
df.loc[df['country'].isin(list_b), 'values_adj'] *= 0.33
```