# Nested If Statement in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a dataframe of financial instrument identifiers

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([["ISIN1", "CUSIP1", "SEDOL1"], 
                  ["ISIN2", "CUSIP2", "SEDOL2"], 
                  ["ISIN3", "CUSIP3", "SEDOL3"], 
                  ["ISIN4", "CUSIP4", "SEDOL4"]], 
                  columns=["ISIN", "CUSIP", "SEDOL"])
```

```
df

    ISIN    CUSIP   SEDOL
0   ISIN1   CUSIP1  SEDOL1
1   ISIN2   CUSIP2  SEDOL2
2   ISIN3   CUSIP3  SEDOL3
3   ISIN4   CUSIP4  SEDOL4
```

Imagine that several entries are missing

```
df.iloc[(1,1)]  = np.nan
df.iloc[(1,2)]  = np.nan
df.iloc[(2,0)]  = np.nan
df.iloc[(3,0)]  = np.nan
df.iloc[(3,1)]  = np.nan
```

```
df

    ISIN    CUSIP   SEDOL
0   ISIN1   CUSIP1  SEDOL3
1   ISIN2   NaN     NaN
2   NaN     CUSIP3  SEDOL3
3   NaN     NaN     SEDOL4
```

In column ID I want to capture a single variable based on this hierarchy : If ISIN is missing, I want to populate CUSIP. If CUSIP is also missing I want to populate SEDOL.

I tried this nested if statement:

```
def identifier(row):

    if ~pd.isnull(row['ISIN']):
        return row['ISIN']
    elif pd.isnull(row['ISIN']) & ~pd.isnull(row['CUSIP']):
        return row['CUSIP']
    elif pd.isnull(row['ISIN']) & pd.isnull(row['CUSIP']) & ~pd.isnull(row['SEDOL']):
        return row['SEDOL']

df['ID'] = df[['SEDOL', 'CUSIP', 'ISIN']].apply(identifier, axis=1)
```

Which returned bad output in the ID column for the last 2 entries.

```
    ISIN    CUSIP   SEDOL   ID
0   ISIN1   CUSIP1  SEDOL1  ISIN1
1   ISIN2   NaN     NaN     ISIN2
2   NaN     CUSIP3  SEDOL3  NaN
3   NaN     NaN     SEDOL4  NaN
```

My expected output is this:

```
    ISIN    CUSIP   SEDOL   ID
0   ISIN1   CUSIP1  SEDOL1  ISIN1
1   ISIN2   NaN     NaN     ISIN2
2   NaN     CUSIP3  SEDOL3  CUSIP3
3   NaN     NaN     SEDOL4  SEDOL4
```

Hope i've explained that well. 
Note that 'ISIN' is a string. There is no use of the .isin function in my code.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you can implement `elif` logic using `np.select`, which is detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194404/create-column-with-elif-in-pandas).

In this case you can do this succinctly with `lookup` + `notnull().idxmax` to find the first non-null value in each row. I added an extra all `NaN` row to show how that is treated.

```
df['ID'] = df.lookup(df.index, df.notnull().idxmax(1))

#    ISIN   CUSIP   SEDOL      ID
#0  ISIN1  CUSIP1  SEDOL1   ISIN1
#1  ISIN2     NaN     NaN   ISIN2
#2    NaN  CUSIP3  SEDOL3  CUSIP3
#3    NaN     NaN  SEDOL4  SEDOL4
#4    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

---

To explain the issue with your original problem, it's the use of `~` with `pd.isnull`.

```
df['ISIN'].apply(lambda x: ~pd.isnull(x))
0   -1
1   -1
2   -2
3   -2
4   -2
Name: ISIN, dtype: int64
```

These are not `0`, so they all evaluate to `True`, meaning for every row you take the `'ISIN'` column. You should use `pd.notnull` (`not pd.isnull` also works) instead of `~pd.isnull`

```
df['ISIN'].apply(lambda x: pd.notnull(x))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
Name: ISIN, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC using `bfill`

```
df['ID']=df.bfill(1).iloc[:,0]
df
Out[346]: 
    ISIN   CUSIP   SEDOL      ID
0  ISIN1  CUSIP1  SEDOL3   ISIN1
1  ISIN2     NaN     NaN   ISIN2
2    NaN  CUSIP3  SEDOL3  CUSIP3
3    NaN     NaN  SEDOL4  SEDOL4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from functools import reduce
df.loc[:, 'ID'] = reduce(lambda c1, c2: c1.combine_first(c2), [df[c] for c in df])
Out[68]: 
    ISIN   CUSIP   SEDOL      ID
0  ISIN1  CUSIP1  SEDOL1   ISIN1
1  ISIN2     NaN     NaN   ISIN2
2    NaN  CUSIP3  SEDOL3  CUSIP3
3    NaN     NaN  SEDOL4  SEDOL4
```