# multiple Elseif conditions in Pandas Dataframe over multiple columns

Tags: pandas, data-manipulation

I am facing a problem in applying multiple Elif condition over a large dataset. The sample data is as below:

```
Id = ['AM12','AM21','AM31','AM41','AM66','AM81','AM77','AM87','AM27','AM69']
Exec = ['Athreyu','Megan','','Omar','Michael','','Oliver','','Jesus','']
AD_Executive= ['','Fer','Virat','John','','John','','','pandya','John']
Ex_FiscId= ['John','Sonal','','Ram','','Anthony','','','Sriju','']
full_nm = ['pulari','','Burgers','Saheb','Bhavya','Borah','Dutta','Upinder','Ruhaan','Rochan']
df_ex = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(Id, full_nm,Exec,AD_Executive,Ex_FiscId)), 
           columns =['Id', 'full_nm','Exec','AD_Executive','Ex_FiscId'])
```

I want to create a new column for Final Name. The condition which I am applying is -

```
def final(df_ex):
   if df_ex['Ex_FiscId'] != np.NaN:
    return df_ex['Ex_FiscId']
  elif (df_ex['Ex_FiscId'] == np.NaN) & (df_ex['AD_Executive'] != np.NaN):
    return df_ex['AD_Executive']
  elif (df_ex['Ex_FiscId'] == np.NaN) & (df_ex['AD_Executive'] == np.NaN) & (df_ex['Exec'] !=np.NaN):
    return df['Exec']
  elif (df_ex['Ex_FiscId'] == np.NaN) & (df_ex['AD_Executive'] == np.NaN) & (df_ex['Exec'] ==np.NaN):
    return df_ex['full_nm']

df_ex['Final'] = df_ex.apply(final, axis = 1)
```

But it is not yielding the desired output. The code only seems to read the first if condition ignoring the other conditions.

I am also attaching the input and desired output table for reference-

| Id | full_nm | Exec | AD_Executive | Ex_FiscId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AM12 | pulari | Athreyu |  | John |
| AM21 |  | Megan | Fer | Sonal |
| AM31 | Burgers |  | Virat |  |
| AM41 | Saheb | Omar | John | Ram |
| AM66 | Bhavya | Michael |  |  |
| AM81 | Borah |  | John | Anthony |
| AM77 | Dutta | Oliver |  |  |
| AM87 | Upinder |  |  |  |
| AM27 | Ruhaan | Jesus | pandya | Sriju |
| AM69 | Rochan |  | John |  |

Desired Output -

| Id | full_nm | Exec | AD_Executive | Ex_FiscId | Final |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AM12 | pulari | Athreyu |  | John | John |
| AM21 |  | Megan | Fer | Sonal | Sonal |
| AM31 | Burgers |  | Virat |  | Virat |
| AM41 | Saheb | Omar | John | Ram | Ram |
| AM66 | Bhavya | Michael |  |  | Michael |
| AM81 | Borah |  | John | Anthony | Anthony |
| AM77 | Dutta | Oliver |  |  | Oliver |
| AM87 | Upinder |  |  |  | Upinder |
| AM27 | Ruhaan | Jesus | pandya | Sriju | Sriju |
| AM69 | Rochan |  | John |  | John |

Comment: Everything, including `np.NaN`, is `!= np.NaN`, so you'd never get past that first block. You should use `pd.isna()` to check if something is null. But really you should implement all of this logic with `np.select`: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194404/create-column-with-elif-in-pandas

Answer (score 0):

let's try this:

```
df['final'] = df_ex.apply(lambda x: x[x[::-1].notnull().idxmax()], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    Id  full_nm     Exec    AD_Executive    Ex_FiscId   final
0   AM12    pulari  Athreyu     NaN            John     John
1   AM21    NaN     Megan       Fer            Sonal    Sonal
2   AM31    Burgers NaN         Virat          NaN      Virat
3   AM41    Saheb   Omar        John           Ram      Ram
4   AM66    Bhavya  Michael     NaN            NaN      Michael
5   AM81    Borah   NaN         John           Anthony  Anthony
6   AM77    Dutta   Oliver      NaN            NaN      Oliver
7   AM87    Upinder NaN         NaN            NaN      Upinder
8   AM27    Ruhaan  Jesus       pandya         Sriju    Sriju
9   AM69    Rochan  NaN         John           NaN      John
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def final(df_ex):
if df_ex['Ex_FiscId'] !="":
    return df_ex['Ex_FiscId']
elif (df_ex['Ex_FiscId']=="") & (df_ex['AD_Executive'] !=""):
    return df_ex['AD_Executive']
elif (df_ex['Ex_FiscId']=="") & (df_ex['AD_Executive'] =="") & (df_ex['Exec'] !=""):
    return df_ex['Exec']
elif (df_ex['Ex_FiscId']=="") & (df_ex['AD_Executive'] =="") & (df_ex['Exec'] ==""):
    return df_ex['full_nm']


df_ex['Final'] = df_ex.apply(final, axis = 1)
```